# Cordova how to POST form data to a REST url

Tags: html, rest, cordova, jakarta-ee

I am creating a very simple demo of `cordova` hybrid mobile project in eclipse with REST. The idea is, I register the details and when I submit the login button, it calls the REST url and saves the login details.

The problem is get `HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type`.

The `index.html` is:

```
<form name="login" id="register" action="http://localhost:8080/peerby/user/" method="post">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input id="fname" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text"/>
            <br>
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input id="lname" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text"/>
            <br>
            <label for="adr">Address</label>
            <input id="adr" name="address" placeholder="Address" type="text"/>
            <br>
            <label for="eml">Email</label>
            <input id="eml" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email"/>
            <br>
            <label for="pswd">Password</label>
            <input id="pswd" name="pasword" placeholder="password" type="password"/>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="log"/>
        </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

This is the `userResorce` file:

```
@Path("user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {

    private UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();

    @GET
    public List<UserModel> getAllUsers() {
        return userDao.getAllUserDao();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userID}")
    public UserModel getUser(@PathParam("userID") Long id) {
        return userDao.getUserDao(id);
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)  //used several mediaType
    public List<UserModel> saveUser(UserModel user) {
        userDao.addUserDao(user);
        return userDao.getAllUserDao();
    }
}
```

Using `Postman` it works fine. But using `cordova`, I get `Unsupported Media Type`. I have used several `MediaType` for `@Consumes`. but all I get is `Unsupported Media Type`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the enctype in your HTML form as below:

`<form name="login" id="register" action="http://localhost:8080/peerby/user/" method="post" enctype='application/json'>`

In your REST controller, consume it as application/JSON,

`@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

After reviewing your code, you are missing the following:

**Dependency in POM.xml**

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> 
<artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId> 
<version>1.8</version>
```

In deployment descriptor (web.xml), you are missing the init param for jersey-serlvet:

```
<init-param> 
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name> 
<param-value>true</param-value> 
</init-param>
```

In your server implementation service, you need to define the resource properly to ensure the request is routed to the right method.

**Class Level annotation:**

```
@Path("/user") 
public class UserResource {
```

**Method level annotation**

```
 @POST 
    @Path("/create") 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public Response saveUser(UserModel user) {
```

After fixing all these, deploy and change your HTML POST action url to "peerby/rest/user/create" to successfully post the data.

Comment: I have set previously `enctype='application/json'` and `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`, but no change. I was getting `Unsupported Media Type`

Comment: Did you debug what was the format you were receiving on the controller?

Comment: you mean the psotman? I used json for POST and GET. I can use GET to display on the cordova simulator with out problems. But I cannot POST to the rest url.

Comment: As per W3C, User agents must support the content types listed below (application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data). Behavior for other content types is unspecified." So, try "multipart/form-data". this should also work.

Comment: I changed the `UserResource` java file's `@POST` method to `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`. Still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145398/discussion-between-yuvi-and-nsv23).